# How to keep a backup git repository in sync with a local one, "git push --mirror" or "git remote update"

Tags: git, git-svn

At work we use svn on the server but I am using git locally (via git-svn) to make use of the speed/branching/commits that aren't ready to share etc.

This is working fine but I'm uncomfortable having changes just one my computer for days on end in case something goes wrong, and would like to have a private backup repo on our file share.

I have created a copy of my local repo using a command like this:

```
git clone --mirror MyRepo z:/MyRepo.git
```

and have added this as a remote to my local with this:

```
git remote add backup z:/MyRepo.git
```

What is the best way of keeping the backup repository in sync with my local one at the end of the day?

I think its one of the following but don't know if they are equivalent or if not what the trade offs are.

1. In local repository: `git push --mirror backup`
2. Or in backup repository: `git remote update`

Or indeed if there is a better way?

Comment: Something like a nightly rsync of your .git directory inside a cron job might be more appropriate than using git itself as a backup solution. If you're looking for a manual method, `git push --mirror` to a bare repository will do.

Comment: @meagar unfortunately we've all got laptops which must be locked away each night so I can't got the cron job way.  Currently doing the git push thing, just want to know if option 2 is essentially the same.

Comment: I use `git push --mirror backup` (backup being my remote backup git repo). I then use a script I wrote if I need to restore from that backup which runs `git fetch backup refs/remotes/*:refs/remotes/*` as well as some git-svn resync stuff (since I don't want to have to parse the whole SVN server as that took a couple of days to get all my projects ported and it only takes minutes -- if that -- to get it cloned and refreshed from my backup).

Comment: I do control both machines though. My dev machine with my local used repo, and my backup machine with my bare backup repo (bare as in `git --init bare`, it still contains all remote branch/tag references) and can be used to restore my local repo in its entirety (including all git-svn metadata).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server with SVN repository, you can use the following scheme: install [SubGit](http://subgit.com) into the SVN repository (it will create a Git repository on the server that will be constantly in sync with the SVN repository, you may consider it as a Git interface to SVN repository).
Then just use pure Git interface (pull, push) instead of git-svn, as if it always were a Git repository. All the changes will automatically synchronized with SVN .
This approach a bit different, than you describe because your have the mirror on the server directly, but could be interesting for you.

Comment: I'm afraid I've got no access to the SVN server, would have been a nice solution.